# "Add another item" slows down the performance and takes more time for loading the page again

Tags: 7, views

We have an option for adding group of value fields in the content page but every time as we add more items and click "Add another item", the page becomes very slow and takes longer time to load.

I am new to Drupal 7 and getting the hang of it slowly.

How to improve the performance and is there any other simple way to implement "add another item?"

Where should I start with? 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you give more details? your question is tagged with 'modules' but there are no modules mentioned... is this an admin page or a a front-facing page? is this a regular page or a view?

Comment: This is an admin page where add content.  Basically we add some project details and that in turn has lot credits associated with the project. These credit details are added via "add another item"

Comment: is this page's URL /node/add/[your_content_type] ?

Comment: yes.. that's correct.

Comment: look in you content type's custom fields /admin/structure/types/manage/[your_content_type]/fields -- let me know what type of field and widget is the field where you enter another item

Comment: It's a field collection type and its an embedded widget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38547/discussion-between-srividhya-and-longboardnode).

Comment: This is an issue with Field Collection module should be entered here https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/field_collection?status=All&categories=All

Comment: @Srividhya are you developing your site locally on your computer? or are you building your site in the cloud (on the internet)?

Comment: @NoSssweat Its locally on my machine. Basically I am talking about one of the admin page where we enter content which uses the add another item and its a field collection module and its a embedded widget. The field collection in turn has term reference field and its a select list.

Comment: @Srividhya perhaps your select list is too long? try using auto-complete widget instead. Also, from my experience, when developing locally Drupal 7 is very slow. Which is why I develop on a cloud server instead, lightning fast.

Comment: @NoSssweat interesting... why do you think locally is slower than cloud? Seems like local should be faster since no send/request over internet..

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes the select list is pretty big. Basically we filter it based on previously selected value. But what happens is every time we load, the select list loads all the items first and then it filters. That adds up the time. Trying to fix that first.  Right now its a select list widget. Let me try the auto complete one may be. Thanks